# How to convert pdf file to tiff, then tiff to pdf with automator?

Tags: applescript, automator, pdf, preview

I have a lot of pdf files with different type of data in it: text, images, stamps etc. And I need to  convert them to look like it's a scanned pdf, i.e. bitmap pdf. I need the same file with the same name in the same folder, but as a bitmap pdf. To do so I:

1. First open pdf file I want to convert in preview.
2. Convert that file as tiff.
3. Then open converted tiff file in preview.
4. Convert it back to pdf.
   How to automate this process with Automator?

Comment: Have you tried the "record" function in Automator?

Comment: @Seamus I tried but it didn't do what I need. It just writes every move I make. And I need to choose pdf files, click on them, and convert to bitmap pdf. Or is it possible to make a folder, and when one moves pdf files to that folder, it automatically convert them to bitmap pdf?